# How to reset map in unloaded chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a Build Battle minigame, and I am using /fill to reset builds. However, the issue is when I use /fill, it is in an unloaded chunk, so I would have to load the chunk somehow, then do the command. I tried using the armor stand spreadplayers method, and it worked, however it seems a bit too tedious and unnecessarily long. Is there any alternates I have?

Comment: If I remember correctly the spawn area chunks are always loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Place the command block in the spawn chunk for the world. this chunk is always loaded and therefore the command will always run when you want it to.